# is there a way to avoid duplicate values in json?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

it runs fine, but every time i rerun it, it adds the id of a user who's already in the json file leading to duplicate values. Any way to fix it?

```
with open('./data/faction1.json','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    faction = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    faction = {}
    faction['users'] = []


class clan(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):

        new_user = ctx.author.id
        if new_user not in faction['users']:
            faction['users'][new_user] = ctx.author.name
            await ctx.send("you have been added to the faction")
            with open('./data/faction1.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(faction, f)
            
        else:
            await ctx.send("already in faction")
```

Comment: json saves keys as strings, but `ctx.author.id` is an integer. Using `new_user = str(ctx.author.id)` could help.

Comment: thnx a ton dude, it worked!!!!@Wups